# verificar si un servicio de accesibilidad esta activado

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Estoy creando un acceso directo a las configuraciones de accesibilidad en android, mi objetivo es después de activar el servicio es que mi aplicacion regrese y ya no muestre el activity que llamar a dicha pantalla.

```
`activarccesibidad = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonaccesibidad);
        activarccesibidad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS), 0);
            }
        });`
```